# Color Shifting Light in the Aframe

Tags: aframe

I want to color shift light in the Aframe scene.

If I want to animate the intensity of the light I will add

```
 animation__intensity=property: light.intensity; from: 0.5; to: 1; dur: 100; dir: alternate; loop: true;
```

So my idea was if I want to color shift the light I will do

```
 animation__color=property: light.color; from: red; to: blue; dur: 100; dir: alternate; loop: true;
```

However, this method does not work. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The color property should be addressed as an rgb vector, like this:

```
animation="property: light.color; from:rgb(200, 70, 30); to:rgb(0, 30, 180); dur: 1500; loop:true; easings: easeInOutSine; dir: alternate; autoplay: true"
```

glitch [here](https://glitch.com/~animate-color)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do you have any idea why it only works for RGB value and hex code and not HTML color names? Because color shift on an object does work with a color name ([glitch example](https://aframecolorshift.glitch.me))? Thanks again.

Comment: My guess is that way is easier to parse and pass values on to the animation component (which is just anime.js under the hood). The docs say that color name should work in animation. https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/animation.html#direct-color-values

Comment: But then higher up on the page under the Properties tables type: `Right now only supports color for tweening isRawProperty color XYZ/RGB vector values.`